# Imported STL files dont look round when rendered

Tags: rendering, import, stl

[image]im currently working on a CAD model (using Siemens NX12) and want a more realistic render than NX is able to provide. I've tried a number of methods and came to the conclusion that exporting as STL file works best. When i import said file into blender and render it, the once round surface looks like its just a high side count polygon. So far i've tried to subdivide the mesh and enable the autosmooth function, but i dont see any improvement. Im really new to blender, i actually downloaded it just for this purpose, so im on the newest version.
I'll try to add one of the renderings, it was done using cycles with a sample rate of 1100 and full hd resolution (cropped to reduce the size) and took just around 90 seconds. You can best see my problem on the inside of the outer ring on the right hand side.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to *select the mesh*, *right-click -> Shade Smooth*. Otherwise I'd recommend add image of your geometry (edit mode).

Comment: What @brockmann said, but also turn on "Auto Smooth" for the Normals settings in the Object Data Properties panel